# Rails numericality validation is failing with a Fixnum value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm using Ruby 2.2.3 with Rails 4.2.8 and Oracle DB. I have a model called `Historico`, which has the following validation:

```
validates :anosemestre, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }
```

Also, in my schema, I have the correct declaration for the anosemestre column:

```
t.integer 'anosemestre'
```

---

I'm trying to clone an old Historico to a new one by doing somethings like (historico_old is fresh from the DB):

```
attributes = historico_old.attributes
attributes.delete('id')
historico_novo = Historico.new(attributes)
binding.pry # for debug, obviously
(...)
historico_novo.save
```

But when I try to save it, the validation fails saying that `anosemestre` is not a number. When I debug it, I get the following output from pry, which made me even more confused:

```
[1] pry(Historico)> historico_novo.valid?
  => false
[2] pry(Historico)> historico_novo.errors.messages
  => {:anosemestre=>["is not a number"]}
[3] pry(Historico)> historico_novo.anosemestre
  => 20171
[4] pry(Historico)> historico_novo.anosemestre.class
  => Fixnum
[5] pry(Historico)> historico_novo.anosemestre = historico_novo.anosemestre.to_i
  => 20171
[6] pry(Historico)> historico_novo.anosemestre.class
  => Fixnum
[7] pry(Historico)> historico_novo.valid?
  => true
```

This issue did not occur in any other model that we have (and we have plenty), and is only happening when I copy the attributes from one historico to another. I have absoloutely no idea how to proceed from here, has anyone else experienced this issue before?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting `attributes`? Could it be that the value is nil?

Comment: Let me get this straight... You're saying that `historico_novo.valid? == true`, but `historico_novo.save` fails with validation errors??!!

Comment: No, historico_novo.save only returns true after I manually set the attribute to the same value but transforming it with `to_i`

Comment: And it's not nil, the value is 20171

Comment: Are you doing anything dodgy in the model? E.g. `def anosemestre; super ||  20171; end`?? That would explain it.

Comment: Or to put this another way, double check what `historico_old.attributes` really returns.

Comment: Nope, I just modify a few other attributes as I need, but this specific one goes straight from the old one's attributes hash without modification

Comment: Ah, apparently someone in the team was resolving an issue and they had to change `anosemestre` inside an unrelated method, which is why I didn't pick it up before. The thing is that we have a wrapper class `Anosemestre` that we use to do some calculations, and it implements `to_int`. That fix was assigning this class to `anosemestre` instead of changing it to integer first. The `to_int` method probably made Ruby think it was a Fixnum, but ActiveRecord was having none of it. Sorry guys.

Comment: Although I find it strange that this `to_int` method makes Ruby think the object is a Fixnum (as it should, according to documentation), but AR ignores it and complains about it. What gives?

Comment: Yeah, we had no hope in guessing that. I'd say my prediction of "something dodgy in the model" was quite accurate though :D

Comment: I just did a little digging; perhaps I could even add this as an answer below? If you look [in the rails source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/numericality.rb#L77-L79), you can see that the validation check actually uses a regex, calling `to_s` on the value. Your `Anosemestre` class will need to implement this method too, in order for the validation to work. Without this, you will have something like `historico_novo.anosemestre.to_s == "#<Anosemestre:0x007ffedfcde458>"` - so the regex fails.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Weird trick for doing this validation, but who am I to judge. Oddly enough, the Anosemestre class also implements to_s, which returns the same value as to_int, except as a string. Indeed it was dodgy hahaha. Funny how in almost every case where there's no logic or reasoning to the issue, the answer is usually some weird or dodgy thing happening.